# shutil.copytree continuously copying the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, shutil

I'm trying to run code that will go through each subdirectory contained in one directory, create a new folder in the subdirectory, and copy all the contents to the new folder.

So if the current folder structure is:

```
Folder 1
-> Subfolder A
-> Subfolder B

Folder 2
-> Subfolder A
-> Subfolder B
```

I want the code to change it to:

```
Folder 1
-> Folder 1 - files
->> Subfolder A
->> Subfolder B

Folder 2
-> Folder 2 - files
->> Subfolder A
->> Subfolder B
```

The following code works on my system, but when I try to run it on the computer I need to make the changes on, it keeps making the extra "- files" folders and looks like:

```
Folder 1
-> Folder 1 - files
->> Folder 1 - files
->>> Folder 1 - files
```

I've tried adding in an ignore function and making changes to the order of the loops, but nothing seems to work on the other person's system (also a Mac running Python 3.7).

...

Here is my current code:

```
import os
import shutil

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def get_subfolders(a_dir):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir, name))]

def ignored_files(adir,filenames):
    return [filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(' - files')]

folders = get_subfolders(folder)

for i in range(0,len(folders)):
    newpath = folders[i] + "/" + folders[i] + " - files"
    subsubfolders = get_subfolders(folders[i])
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        shutil.copytree(folders[i], newpath, ignore=ignored_files)
        print(folders[i])
        for x in range(0, len(subsubfolders)):
            if os.path.exists(newpath + "/" + subsubfolders[x]):
                shutil.rmtree(folders[i] + "/" + subsubfolders[x])
    else:
        print("folder exists already")
```

Comment: Why not just filter on *files* instead of directories, and then use `shutil.copy()`? Then you don't have to filter, and you don't have to remove the subsubfolders again (which you really should have included in the filter instead).

Comment: The code otherwise looks reasonably sane (apart from not using `os.path.join()` to do the path element joining). Are you certain that the other person is running the right piece of code? Perhaps insert some print statements to debug what is going on there.

Comment: Last but not least, consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of using `os.path`, for a cleaner API for this sort of thing: `HERE = Path(__file__).resolve().parent`, then `folders = [p for in HERE.iterdir() if p.is_dir()]` to get a series of folders. Per folder, target a subdir with `target = folder / folder.name + " - files"`, test if it exists with `target.exists()` and copy stuff to it with a loop over `folder.iterdir()`, testing for files with `.is_file()` and then just use `shutil.copy(from_path, target)`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I've made these changes, but haven't been able to get the final loop to work - I can make it test for files or directories, but how do I make it check for any contents and copy them to the target?

When I use shutil.copy, it's creating a blank file instead of the "- files" directory.

Comment: I also haven't found a way to _move_ the subfolders to the new "- files" folder, rather than just copying them.